# Partial View does not load in main view for the second iteration

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have got main page, from which I am loading a dialogue, in which I am loading a main view and a partial view into a div elements.
i.e. Main page -> Click link--> Open a dialogue--> Load Main view into a Div element--> Load partial view into a div element in Main view.

Issue: flow works fine for the first iteration, and for the second iteration, the Partial view alone does not render.

Partial view gets loaded into the `SkillresultDiv` element for the first iteration.  However, when the user closes the dialogue and re-opens again, the partial view alone does not get load. Any idea what am I missing? But when I move to different page, and comes back to the same page again, then everything works fine.

Main.cshtml file

```
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("UpdateSkill", "AddNewSkill", "Manager", new { @class = "mypopup" })
</div>
<script src="~/Scripts/DMPScript/Manager.js"></script>

Inside Manager.js file

$('.mypopup').click(function () {
debugger;
var fname = $("#FirstName").val();
var lname = $("#LastName").val();
$('<div/>').appendTo('body').dialog({
    close: function (event, ui) {
        },
        modal: true,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 800,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        position: { my: "top", at: "top", of: window },
        title: 'Add/View Skill - ' + lname +',' + fname
}).load(this.href, {});

return false;
});

inside Mainskillview.cshtml
   <div id="SkillresultDiv"></div>
<script src="~/Scripts/DMPScript/AddEditSkill.js"></script>

Partial view gets load into the above tag, and the code for that is    included in the AddEditskill.js script


$(document).ready(function () {

    getSkillinfo();

});



function getSkillinfo() {
    debugger;
    $('#SkillresultDiv').html('');
    var id = $('#ResourceId').val();
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "/Manager/Getskillinfo",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            Rid: id
        },
    });

    request.done(function (result) {
        if (result != null) {
            $('#SkillresultDiv').html(result);
        }
        else {
            $('#noResultErrorMsg').removeProp('hidden');
        }
    });

    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        $('#SkillresultDiv').html(jqXHR.responseText);
    });
}
```

Comment: please [edit question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43331737/edit) with code updates so they can be formatted and easily read by all. Comment blocks are not very easy to read for a lot of code

Answer (score 0):

i have fixed the issue, by nullifying the Div element which holds the partial html page.  i.e.  nullify the partial element, and reload the html content.